# Retry the Ajax call after five seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In this snippet, $.ajax(this) in error is making five ajax calls as I needed but I need five seconds delay between each request. Please help!

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(download),
  contentType: "application/json",
  url: '',
  retryCount: 1,
  retryLimit: 5,
  success: function(data) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '',
    })
        .success(function(data) {

    })
        .error(function(data) {

    })
  },
 //It has to go into error
  error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    this.retryCount++;
    if (this.retryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
      //try again
      $.ajax(this);
      return;
    } else {
      //user comes here After trying in the if loop for 5 times, with each request having five seconds delay. I am not able to keep delay between each request
    }
    return;
  }

});
```

Comment: have you considered using a setTimeout for the delay aspect of your code?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    this.retryCount++;
    if (this.retryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
      //try again
      var ajaxObject = this;
      window.setTimeout(function(){
          $.ajax(ajaxObject);
      },5000);

      return;
    } else {
      //user comes here After trying in the if loop for 5 times, with each request having five seconds delay. I am not able to keep delay between each request
    }
    return;
  }
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot Daniel and one simple question. I have five anchor tags assume <a classs="m"></a> <a class="n"></a> <a class="o"></a>. Do you know how to select particular anchor from jquery

Comment: $("a.m") $("a.o") etc

Comment: I have one bug in the previous code. how to disable to button to avoid making another new call while this requests are going on

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your Ajax call like this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $.ajax(this);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: `function() =` - some new syntax? :p

Comment: lol sorry I was typing on phone and must have been a typo:) I have been using a lot of arrow functions lately and probably slipped that in by mistake.